# Why video corrupted in receiver of UDP streaming in python?

Tags: python, opencv, tcp

I want to broadcast video from my webcam to all computer in a network.
I am using [this](https://github.com/andrew-wja/roboclub-video/blob/master/VideoSender.py) code to send video and [this](https://github.com/andrew-wja/roboclub-video/blob/master/VideoReceiver.py) code to receive video.Now i can view the video from webcam in receiver.But video is  corrupted by some black lines. How can i remove the black lines?

Comment: That is quite a lot of code for a question here. Are you sure you're not dropping packets, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your send code has no transmit pacing. If you're going to use UDP instead of TCP, you have to do everything TCP does that UDP doesn't by yourself if you need it. One of the things TCP does is transmit pacing -- slow start, exponential backoff, and so on. You can't just fire datagrams at the network at full CPU speed and expect them to get through.

You can probably fake it just by putting an appropriate delay after each UDP send call.